# SVG viewbox overflow: hidden / crop

Tags: svg

Is there a way to make anything outside the `viewBox` invisible? As if the `viewBox` itself were an element with `overflow: hidden`

In the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36LRK/), you can see the `viewBox` highlighted in blue.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 100">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
    <text y="10" x="10%" width="10%" height="200%" fill="#000" font-size="30" >
        Only the part inside the viewBox should be visible
    </text>
</svg>
```

[image: Only the part inside the viewBox should be visible]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the rectangle as a `<clipPath>`:

```
<defs>
    <rect id="rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
    <clipPath id="clip">
        <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
```

and then apply it to a `<g>` element which contains your text (and anything else you want to clip:

```
<g clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <text y="10" x="10%" width="10%" height="200%" fill="#000" font-size="30">Only the part inside the viewBox should be visible</text>
</g>
```

Since the `<rect>` was used only to shape the `clipPath`, you have to redraw it:

```
<use xlink:href="#rect"/>
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36LRK/2/)**

Comment: It looks like you can use  `clip-path="url(#clip)"` directly on the `svg` tag, so no need for an extra `g` tag.

Comment: @bfred.it This doesn't always seem to work in Edge/IE. Any advice?