# Can some parts of svg element be rendered outside SVG element itself by a browser?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a d3.js chart which is SVG consisting of many elements. Tooltips being shown on user mouseover. Most right and left tooltip are partly hidden with plot edges (they are cutted by svg element edges, similar how overflow:hidden will cut absolute positioned elements when they go outside parent with overflow:hidden).

So can i show them anyway ouside of SVG broders?

Comment: Check this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074216/svg-viewbox-overflow-hidden-crop

Comment: Not just similar to overflow:hidden, but in fact exactly the same as overflow:hidden so just set overflow:visible on the outer <svg> element.

Comment: @robert-longson please make your comment as the answer, i will mark it as right one. Doent know how i missedsomething it, i was cheking for overflow hidden in all ancestors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set overflow:visible on the outer `<svg>` element. SVG uses the same CSS property as html here.